# Multer posting twice when creating data

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, mean-stack, multer

I don't know why multer post my data twice here, What is wrong here? This outputs 2 results in my mongodb. I've been following solutions but it doesn't do anything, any help

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:function(req,file,cb){
        cb(null,'./public/assets/images');
    },
    filename:function(req,file,cb){
        if(!file.originalname.match(/\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$/)){
            var err = new Error();
            err.code = 'filetype';
            return cb(err);
        }else{
            imageName =  "assets/images/" + Date.now() + '_' + file.originalname;
            cb(null, Date.now() + '_' + file.originalname);
        }   
    }
})

var uploaduser = multer({
    storage:storage,
    limits:{fileSize:10000000}
}).single('myuser');

router.post('/users', parser.single("myuser"), function(req, res) {
   myImage = imageName.toString('base64');
   user.user_image = myImage;
   user.save(function(err) {});
   uploaduser(req,res,function(err){})
});
```

Comment: are you saving images in database or to a file system ?

Comment: `parser.single` means ?

Comment: i save my image to folder, then image path as string to database